# How to select certain numbers of groups in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the table with data:
[image: ID|]
    And for this table I need to create pegination by **productId** column. I know about LIMIT N,M, but it works with rows and not with groups. For examle for my table with pegination = 2 I expect to retrieve all 9 records with **productId** = 1 and 2 (the number of groups is 2).

**So how to create pegination by numbers of groups ?**

I will be very thankfull for answers with example.

Comment: Post your code and where it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do pagination by groups is to assign a product sequence to the query.  Using variables, this requires a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@p = productid, @rn + 1,
                        if(@rn := productid, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from table t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @p := -1) vars
      order by t.productid
     ) t
where rn between X and Y;
```

With an index on `t(productid)`, you can also do this with a subquery.  The condition can then go in a `having` clause:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(distinct productid)
        from t t2
        where t2.productid <= t.productid)
       ) as pno
from t
having pno between X and Y;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from
(select * from <your table> where <your condition> group by <with your group>)
LIMIT number;
```